# emacs search and list multi partlines

Tags: emacs

Search for multiline in an xml file with emacs

```
 m-x list-matching-lines

      <step>D</step>
      <alter>0</alter>
      <octave>5</octave>
```

It lists all occurances in the *occur* window.

But if I search a multi partline it fails.

```
 m-x list-matching-lines

     <step*
     <alter*
     <octave*

 Searched 1 buffer; no matches for `<step*^J     <alter*^J     <octave*'
```

The search only with

```
m-x list-matching-lines

     <step*
```

works also perfekt.

The outcome with above command looks like:

```
177:        <stem default-y="-57">down</stem>
182:          <step>A</step>
190:        <stem default-y="-60">down</stem>
200:          <step>D</step>
208:        <stem>down</stem>
216:          <step>D</step>
224:        <stem>down</stem>
```

I appreciate some help, thanks.

Comment: FYI `list-matching-lines` is an alias for `occur` which has a standard binding of `M-s o` -- which is going to prove rather more convenient, if you use the command regularly.

Comment: m-x list-matching-lines <step...* C-q C-j RET will bring the searched line or <step...* 
 ...* lines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found something in the green.

```
 m-x list-matching-lines    

 <step...*
```

+ <kbd>C-q</kbd><kbd>C-j</kbd><kbd>RET</kbd> will bring the searched line plus the next one in the *Occur* window.

and

```
m-x list-matching-lines    

 <step...* 
 ...*
```

+ <kbd>C-q</kbd><kbd>C-j</kbd><kbd>RET</kbd> brings the desired two lines etc.

Answer (score 1):

`<step*` will match `<ste` and `<step` and `<steppppppppp` etc. Nothing else. It's a regular expression, not a shell glob pattern. So it certainly isn't going to match `<step>D</step>`.

Use `.*` to match zero or more non-newline characters; not just `*`

Read about regular expressions in the manual:
<kbd>C-h</kbd><kbd>i</kbd><kbd>g</kbd> `(emacs) Regexps` <kbd>RET</kbd>